# Conan comic from the perspective of a winged demon amongst temple ruins in the desert, reflecting on its wretched existence, which Conan slays

Tags: comics, episode-identification, conan

I have been searching for a particular Conan comic story for a very long time. I do not recall which series it is hence the difficulty.

The story is from the perspective of a winged demon amongst temple ruins in the desert, reflecting on its wretched existence when once long before it was worshipped and showered with gifts. Now it survives by preying upon the odd straggler or passer by and at the end of the story Conan arrives out of the desert, fights the demon and slays it and heads off into the wilderness.

The demon was bald and the comic itself was black and white.

It was definitely a comic book story, not a strip. Does anybody know which one?

Comment: I know you're looking for a comic strip, but it might be helpful to identify the original story (if any) it was adapted from. I'm not a Conan expert, but I can suggest one possibility: Conan slays a winged demon in ["Queen of the Black Coast"](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/42183). Jungle setting rather than desert, so probably not the same story.

Comment: If it was a black-and-white comic book, I think that indicates something from *The Savage Sword of Conan* series.

Comment: Scanned versions of all the issues can be found online (although watch out for spyware!).  I skimmed through the first twenty or so and didn't find the page in question.  After a while, all those black-and-white drawings of Conan slashing people start to look the same.

Comment: This sounds  vaguely like "The Forever Phial" from Savage Sword of Conan #8, written by Roy Thomas and gorgeously drawn by Tim Conrad. However, the character is a wingless wizard, not a winged demon. You can read the entire story here: http://bronzeageofblogs.blogspot.com/2015/07/tim-conrads-conan.html

Comment: This is not the story because its not a winged demon its a wingless wizard as you say! It is gorgeously drawn though I agree...

Answer (score 4):

I know you said a comic strip, but this description brought to mind the monster from *Conan* comic book issue no. 9, specifically as it appears on [page 10 of the issue](http://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Conan-the-Barbarian-1970/Issue-9?id=17247#10).

[image: The Garden of Fear]

Obviously, this also takes place in a garden, not the desert, but the location is pretty desolate.

There are also black-and-white reprint versions of this comic, like this one from *Conan Saga* no. 3.

[image: Page from Conan Saga #3]

Comment: That's not it because the Demon I remember was bald and the comic story was black and white. However, You are right in that it was a comic book story not a strip-my bad!

Comment: @MattGibson The story was published in black and white too, for example in Conan Saga #3. I have added one page from it that match your description somewhat.